# Deduction Theorem and $\nvdash$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The deduction theorem states the following

$$\Gamma\cup\{A\}\vdash B \Longrightarrow\ \Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B.\quad\quad (*)$$

The converse of $(*)$ also holds. I wonder if we also have the following in $(**)$?

$$\Gamma\cup\{A\}\nvdash B \Longrightarrow\ \Gamma\nvdash A\rightarrow B. \quad\quad (**)$$

And what about the converse of $(**)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The key to this is **contraposition**: A statement of the form "$A \implies B$" is equivalent to "not $B$ $\implies$ not $A$". Also note that "not $\vdash$" is the same as "$\nvdash$".

From the converse

$$\Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B \Longrightarrow \Gamma\cup\{A\}\vdash B$$

we can infer by contraposition

$$\Gamma\cup\{A\}\nvdash B \Longrightarrow\ \Gamma\nvdash A\rightarrow B. \quad\quad (**)$$

And the converse of this statement,

$$\Gamma\nvdash A\rightarrow B \Longrightarrow \Gamma\cup\{A\}\nvdash B$$

is the contraposition of the left-to-right direction of the deduction theorem:

$$\Gamma\cup\{A\}\vdash B \Longrightarrow\ \Gamma\vdash A\rightarrow B.\quad\quad (*)$$

and thus also holds.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive of $(**)$ is effectively just modus ponens.  Has nothing to do with the deduction theorem.